# Why does my iTerm2 launch with an X in it's path?

Tags: command-line, iterm

After upgrading to El Capitan, then working on installing Rails, my iTerm2 shell now opens with `x >`, instead of just `>`.

Can someone please explain why this is happening, and help me figure out how to return it to it's normal *home*?

[image]

Comment: When I type `pwd`, the `x` disappears immediately and I am in $HOME, which for me is `/users/randytolentino`.

I would love for this question to be appropriated to the write SE forum - I'll look into having it moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been figured out. There was a leftover RVM script in the `.zlogin` file that was causing this error, and when I imploded RVM (to use rbenv), I forgot to remove this script.

Thanks to @sushihangover for the willingness to help!

Answer (score 2):

You have `shell integration` installed and the last command executed failed:

Example:

[image]

`DoesNotExist` cmd does not exist, thus an error 127:

[image]

> Command status
>
> The mark on a command line will turn red if a command fails. You can right click the mark to view its return code.

Re: https://iterm2.com/shell_integration.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Considering that this behavior occurs when I launch a new session of iTerm2, how can I find out what the error/code was?

Right clicking on the `x` does not give me the same menu as the image you posted above. It just opens up a typical menu with options like "New Menu", "New Tab", etc.

Comment: Not sure why right-clicking on the `mark` would not present the last cmd context menu... but in terms of last error I would look at the end of your `.zshrc` ... simple test, add a `pwd $(HOME)` at the very end, does the error mark go away on a new zsh?

Comment: adding `pwd $(HOME)` gave me a `command not found: HOME`

Comment: sorry... fat-fingered... just `pwd` or `cd $HOME`, just some command that will produce an `exit 0` result

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping me out.

`pwd` had no effect when I closed out iTerm2 and relaunched it. 

`cd $HOME` just basically outputted the home directory `/users/randytolentino` then on the next line, still getting `x  >`

Comment: Which version of iTerm2 are you using, i'm running 2.9.20151229 and in the profiles that I use zsh in, it starts up and shows a green mark... if you have the same version, file a bug/issue and see if the developers can help... it really is not hurting anything as it just shows the status of the last exit code...